# matplotlib trick to have unequal space beween each integer on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

here is a code that mimic a distribution and make a stacked histogram plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1f2=[(i**6-int(i**6))/5 for i in np.random.exponential(0.8, size=100)]
widz=[i*(1/max(f1f2)) for i in f1f2]

pos=[i for i in range(100)]
f1=[np.random.uniform()*i for i in f1f2]
f2=[s-i for s,i in zip(f1f2,f1)]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,2), constrained_layout=False)
ax = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=1, ncols=1, hspace=0).subplots(sharex=True)
ax.bar(pos, f1,
        color="red",
        edgecolor="none",width=widz)
ax.bar(pos, f2,
        bottom=f1,
        color="blue",
        edgecolor="none",width=widz)
```

And here is the result :
[image: And here is the result :]

I would like the exact same width for each bar (proportional to the sum of the 2 values) but without space between each bar. So the x axis will be hard to read .. yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like the exact same width for each bar (proportional to the sum of the 2 values) but without space between each bar.

If I understand correctly, setting the position of each bar so that it falls after the width of the previous one should do what you want.

Especially:

- The first position should be zero,
- The second position should be the width of the first bar,
- The third position should be the cumulative width of the first and second bars,
- and so on ...

```py
# [...]

cs_widths = np.cumsum(widz)
pos = np.concatenate([ [0], cs_widths[:-1] ])  # instead of range(100)

# [...]
```

Changing the `pos` variable that way and setting the alignment mode to "edge" (`align="edge"` in the `bar()` calls) should give you the following figure. Note that the remaining white spaces are because of very small bars.

[image]

---

As pointed out by [@Tranbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13525512/tranbi), the axis `xticks` now range from `0` to `sum(widz)`. If needed, you can relabel the `xticks` to keep the original `[0,100]` range.

```py
# Example with ticks every 5 bars, ranging from 0 to 100
ticks_labels = range(100)
ax.set_xticks(pos[::5], labels=ticks_labels[::5])
```

Although, as you mention, "the x axis will be hard to read". Some tick labels will probably overlap.

[image]

Comment: Great solution! You can also keep the original `pos` as `pos_lbl` to label your xticks, e.g.: `ax.set_xticks(pos[::5], labels=pos_lbl[::5])`

Comment: @Tranbi yes you can set custom tick labels so that it still ranges from 0 to 100. However, with the very thin bars in the figure, some ticks will overlap.

Comment: You're right, some ticks might overlap, but I think this is what OP meant with "unequal space"